# New linux with old kernel in chroot

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel

I have access to enterprise level server, but it have kernel version

```
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Release:        6.4
Codename:       Santiago

2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 -> 2013
```

I need new stuff like python 2.7.9, MongoDB 2.6, and so one.

By the way, I did not have any kind of root access, I can only ask someone to run some commands with root permission, and that's all. To enter chroot, I can ask to create some kind of executable with SUID and right arguments to chroot command + mounts.

Actuall question are: what the most new distro I can use to satisfy my requirements? On weekends I will try to get RHEL 6.4 and install it on my home PC and try to make this situation under my control and get any usefull information.

- I love ArchLinux, but not sure for 2.6.32 and systemd and last updates.
- Ubuntu 14.04(14.10) uses 3.* kernel vesion and I'm not sure about it.
- Or anything else? Fedora? Gentoo? CentOS?

Comment: but have you found some problem using python 2.7.9 and MongoDB 2.6 with kernel version 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

Comment: I feel as though you are possibly working towards a goal you might not actually need or want to work towards. What are your end goals? Just to have more up to date software? What is your environment? What are your limitations?

Comment: My goals to have root inside chroot, to make what i want, and have fresh software. and manipulate it. So, but I don't have root permission on this server.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use chroot or any container implementation, since they will run under host kernel. You have to use a VM ran under some of available hypervisors - like `KVM/QEMU`, `Xen`, `VMWare` or `VirtualBox`.

Though I highly doubt your initial problem has something to do with a kernel version.
There's plenty of ways to get the new versions of software running on your system. The most easy one - compile everything needed from sources and install in custom `PREFIX`, like in your own home directory. This way you won't even need the root privileges. Only some significant space.

Comment: Yeah, It's really good way to do it, but this server will never use any kind ov Virtualization or Containerization. Does any anyone know, how to install software with prefix? So, like minimal installation of any distro from scratch? Main issue, is that resolve.conf on this server are empty, and DNS are not working, and i want to use my own inside my prefix.

Comment: `tar xvzf <tarball>`, then `cd <dir>`, `./configure --prefix=~/usr`, `make all install` - only gcc, gmake id needed for that.